# Correct XPath to fetch an element depending on a nested attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following XML (this is actually a valid snipped of a much larger document)

```
<gmd:MD_Metadata>
    <gmd:identificationInfo>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
            <gmd:citation>
                <gmd:CI_Citation>
                    <gmd:date>
                        <gmd:CI_Date>
                            <gmd:date>
                                <gco:DateTime>2020-11-13T00:00:00</gco:DateTime>
                            </gmd:date>
                            <gmd:dateType>
                                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="creation"/>
                            </gmd:dateType>
                        </gmd:CI_Date>
                    </gmd:date>
                    <gmd:date>
                        <gmd:CI_Date>
                            <gmd:date>
                                <gco:DateTime>2020-11-13T00:00:01</gco:DateTime>
                            </gmd:date>
                            <gmd:dateType>
                                <gmd:CI_DateTypeCode codeList="CI_DateTypeCode" codeListValue="lastRevision"/>
                            </gmd:dateType>
                        </gmd:CI_Date>
                    </gmd:date>
                </gmd:CI_Citation>
            </gmd:citation>
        </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
    </gmd:identificationInfo>
</gmd:MD_Metadata>
```

`//gco:DateTime` gives me two results.

How can I fetch only the one with `<gco:DateTime>2020-11-13T00:00:01</gco:DateTime>` knowing that:

- I do not know the value of `DateTime` beforehand
- I cannot take for granted that the `DateTime` element I want is always the second one
- I need the `DateTime` element where `//gmd:CI_DateTypeCode[@codeListValue='lastRevision']`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a predicate on an ancestor e.g. `gmd:CI_Date[.//gmd:CI_DateTypeCode[@codeListValue='lastRevision']]//gco:DateTime`.